# Facebook App Invites not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have integrated the facebook sdk in my app.I have a listview with a onitemclicklistener.On press of a particular item at a particular position ,I trigger the facebbok appinvite code

```
String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

                appLinkUrl = "//my app url here";
                previewImageUrl="//my preview image url here";

                if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                            .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                            .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                            .build();
                    AppInviteDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
                }
```

But the invite is not working.A circle appears after sometimes and a screen flashes and disappears after some milliseconds and nothing happens .No invite dialog appears ,no friends selection and no invite is sent to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the invite working you need to go to the app review status and make your app live to the public.